# How to install SVN on Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

I want to install svn repository. Is there any differences between Subclipse and Subversion?

I searched everywhere about Subversion but I couldn't find something about Subversion, all I got is Subclipse. Could you give me some instruction how to do it?

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do.  Do you want to create a repository, or get a svn client for Eclipse?

Comment: I don'tknow  what is called. I want  checkout some projects from svn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Eclipse help menu you have to go under "Eclipse Marketplace", type "svn" into the search box and press enter.
You'll see all svn plugins available for Eclipse.

Choose your SVN plugin, press "install" and follow the guided procedure.

Actually, as far I know, the most popular are Subversive and Subclipse.

Answer (score 5):

SubEclipse is an Eclipse Plugin that let's you connect to your Subversion repositories. To install an SVN repository you need another software, that is beyond Eclipse capabilities. See http://www.tonyspencer.com/2007/03/02/setup-a-subversion-server-in-4-minutes/

Answer (score 4):

1)Open eclipse help -->install new software-->(in front of work with combo)press add

Name:-some_name
 Location:-"http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/2.0/update-site/"

2)Then wait for some time it will search for plugins and install required plugins

3)install required plugins...!

that's it..!
make sure you have working internet connection and packages fails some times if you have already installed some of plugins or their older versions.